# Merging all columns preferentially by column count

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to figure out how to merge all columns of a dataframe into a new column while highgrading the columns by highest count #.  So in the example below data from GRR would be preferntially loaded in to the new column over GRD.  My example only has two columns but would also need to iterate over a variable column number.

Example:

```
    print(df2[Matches].describe())
         GR2         GRD           GRR
count    200   9106.000000  18894.000000

DEPT      GRR     GRD         GR2        MERGED
0  400.0  NaN  45.007000   60            45.007000
1  400.5  35   42.575001   42.575001     35
2  401.0  NaN  43.755001   40            43.755001
3  401.5  40      Nan      45.417000     40
4  402.0  45      NaN         NaN        45
```

Comment: You might want to look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: You might want to provide some concrete output so we don't have to _guess_ what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This rearranges your dataframe so that the column with the highest count is on the left, followed by columns in descending order of their `count` value.

```
df[df.describe().loc['count'].sort_values(ascending=False).index]

# Create sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({c: range(5) for c in 'ABC'})
df.loc[:2, 'A'] = None
df.loc[0, 'B'] = None
>>> df
    A   B  C
0 NaN NaN  0
1 NaN   1  1
2 NaN   2  2
3   3   3  3
4   4   4  4

# Sort columns by count.
>>> df[df.describe().loc['count'].sort_values(ascending=False).index]
   C   B   A
0  0 NaN NaN
1  1   1 NaN
2  2   2 NaN
3  3   3   3
4  4   4   4
```

Comment: A cool trick I picked up from ayhan the other day which involves argsort: `df.iloc[:, df.describe().loc['count'].mul(-1).argsort()]`

Answer (score 1):

Sort by counts, then find first non-null value.

```
priority = df1.loc['count'].sort_values(ascending=False).index

df.assign(MERGED=df.lookup(
    df.index,
    df[priority].notnull().idxmax(1)
))

    DEPT   GRR        GRD        GR2     MERGED
0  400.0   NaN  45.007000  60.000000  45.007000
1  400.5  35.0  42.575001  42.575001  35.000000
2  401.0   NaN  43.755001  40.000000  43.755001
3  401.5  40.0        NaN  45.417000  40.000000
4  402.0  45.0        NaN        NaN  45.000000
```

---

Where

```
df

    DEPT   GRR        GRD        GR2
0  400.0   NaN  45.007000  60.000000
1  400.5  35.0  42.575001  42.575001
2  401.0   NaN  43.755001  40.000000
3  401.5  40.0        NaN  45.417000
4  402.0  45.0        NaN        NaN
```

And

```
df1

       GR2     GRD      GRR
count  200  9106.0  18894.0
```